# Is there a way to group parameters together in Sphinx without there being a class above?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to document a list of common parameters that exist in a few classes. However, I would prefer not to repeat the documentation and instead have the list of common parameters show up in only one place.

Usually, in Sphinx, you can do something like

```
.. autofunction:: foo
   :param str a: description of a
   :param int b: description of b
```

And it will give an output of the format

```
foo
Parameters: - a (str) - description of a
            - b (str) - description of b
```

However, since these parameters are all common, I would like to do this without using any autofunction type thing. I've created a custom extension that can take docstrings for individual parameters, and put them in the format

```
:param str a: description of a
:param int b: description of b
```

But I cannot seem to get the same output, and I'm instead getting this

[image: bad output]